# Proving $\arctan x = 2 \arctan \frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}$, starting from the integral representation of $\arctan$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

Starting from the integral representation of the arctan function, $$\arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2},$$how does one prove the (half-angle) identity? $$\arctan x = 2 \arctan \frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$

I am interested in a clever change of variables that should do the trick. However, I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you differentiate$$2\arctan\left(\frac t{1+\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right),$$then you get $\frac1{1+t^2}$. So\begin{align}2\arctan\left(\frac x{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)&=2\arctan\left(\frac x{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)-2\arctan\left(\frac0{1+\sqrt{1+0^2}}\right)\\&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}\\&=\arctan(x).\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely one way of proving it. However, I am more interested in finding a change of variable which does the job.

Comment: @PolyPhys: You should be clear in your question that you *want* a change-of-variable solution (not just that you're *unable to find* one). This will help people avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) presenting other approaches.

Comment: @Blue: I sincerely apologize! I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: I would like to apologize for not being more precise in the formulation of my question.